# Twilio Studio IVR - Is there a way to play a default error message and return to the most recent Gather widget when invalid digits are entered?

Tags: twilio, ivr, twilio-studio

I know that I can accomplish this for a single Split widget by connecting the "No Condition Matches" transition to a Say/Play widget and then transition that back to the previous Gather, but is there a way of dynamically determining the last-played Gather so that I don't need a new Say/Play widget for every Split in my flow?

Comment: So is the goal to have one Say/Play widget to handle all exceptions (where the choice is invalid or the choice timesout)?

Comment: Correct.  My flow is already pretty bloated so I'd prefer to avoid adding an extra Say/Play per split just to direct the call back to the correct gather prompt since I want it to say the same verbiage regardless of where the exception comes up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, the answer is no. You would need to specify a new widget for each gather widget's error case.